# displaying dynamic values in jsp without usinf scriplet using struts mvc

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jdbc, struts

i am using mvc struts framework in my web application.
i am displaying dynamic values from my database in jsp page using scrilets `<% %>`
its been bad practice doing that way but i followed links of how to do it without scriptlets but cant understand much ..i am using struts and i have action and bean class
this is my jsp page

```
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="com.pra.sql.SQLC"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<table align="left" width="346" border="0">
    <tr><td align="center" colspan="2" style="font-size:20px;">Tests We Provide</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="194" height="52" align="left" nowrap>Test Name</th>
        <th width="142" align="left" nowrap>Test Fee</th>
    </tr>
    <%
        String sql = "Select tname,tfee from addtest order by tname";
        ResultSet rs = SQLC.getData(sql, null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String testname = rs.getString("tname");
            String testfee = rs.getString("tfee");
    %>
    <tr>
        <td width="194" height="30" nowrap><%=testname%></td>
        <td width="142" nowrap><%=testfee%></td>
    </tr>  
    <%
        }
    %>
</table>
```

please tell me how i display testnames and fees by writing code in formbean and retreive each value one by one from bean to jsp ..
please tell me how i can do this without using scriplets..
answer in steps would be really appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move you db reading code to action controller. It should read values you need from db and put it into request or model.

Than use jstl to output your values (in jsp):

```
<c:out value="${parameterFromRequest}"/>
```

Define bean:

```
public class MyBean {
    private final String tName;
    private final String tFee;

    public MyBean(String tName, String tFee) {
        this.tName = tName;
        this.tFee = tFee;
    }

    public String getTName() {
        return tName;
    }

    public String getTFee() {
        return tFee;
    }
}
```

Create collection in action controller:

```
String sql = "Select tname,tfee from addtest order by tname";
ResultSet rs = SQLC.getData(sql, null);
Collection<MyBean> myBeans = new ArrayList<MyBean>();
while (rs.next()) {
    String testname = rs.getString("tname");
    String testfee = rs.getString("tfee");
    myBeans.add(new MyBean(testname, testfee));
}

request.setAttribute("myBeans", myBeans);
```

Access in jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="myBean" items="${myBeans}">
    Name: <c:out value="${myBean.tName}"/>
    Fee: <c:out value="${myBean.tFee}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: u mean to say when i click on link then using ajax i call some method and in that method i call function which i created in my action controller .in that function i write my db reading code ..

Comment: while (rs.next()) {
            String testname = rs.getString("tname");
            String testfee = rs.getString("tfee");

Comment: where i store these values in action controller

Comment: yes. You process ajax request in action controller. You can return this jsp and in javascript put it as html content of some div. In common it is calling MVC - you have model, thats holds all data (it is formed in controller), controller - that handle requests, and view - it should not get data from db or prepare model, only display data from model that controller prepare.

Comment: If you call in controller: request.setAttribute("myAttribute", "some value"); than in jsp you can access it with ${myAttribute}. To output this value you can use jstl from answer (it will escape special characters).

Comment: but i want to get all values from database column (while(rs.next))  ..will it be helpfull still ?

Comment: Create a bean that will represent single value. Read tham all from db in action controller, put in collection: Collection<MyBean> myBeans. Than put this collection of beans in request. In jsp itterate with <c:forEach var="myBean" items="${myBeans}"><c:out value="${myBean.propertyName}"/></c:forEach>

Comment: sorry bro but just not getting how to do it ive used ajax .. forwarded ..and written code =hmm but cant understand all code please modify it ..
        String sql = "Select f_name,l_name,userid from mainreg where type='Patient' and verified='Y' order by f_name";
        ResultSet rs = SQLC.getData(sql, null);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String fname = rs.getString("f_name");
            String lname = rs.getString("l_name");
            String usrid = rs.getString("userid");
        }
        Collection<MyBEan> mybeans;
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

Comment: how to do this Collection part ?

Comment: sorry bro but i cant see database values on my jsp

Comment: ive used lookupdispatchaction in my action so many functions ive been using in same actionclass and one formbean ..ive did as u told but no value ..

Comment: The common flow should work. Should be some error in query or something else. If you put collection into request - it should be available in view you return in same method that put collection in request.

Comment: thank alot ..it worked already .. though instead of collections i used Liat ..but i have problem i have all functions of my web application in one bean (MyBean) and in this values are setting into constructor ..but i need to do desame for other functions but already its argument are set as u did how i can use for others ..

Comment: I made it immutable, you can remove final modifier for fields of MyBean and add settters. Than you can set it after bean creation

Comment: so means there is no need of construtctor and i can set values of fields with getter and setter ..i tried this but it say error as no property found something

Comment: No, you nead to call empty constructor: MyBean bean = new MyBean(); bean.setTFee("fe value");

Comment: now this is my jsp
<c:forEach  var="myBeans" items="${myBeans}">
                    <tr> <td nowrap="nowrap" id="mytd"> 
                            <a href="#" onclick="trial('${myBeans.userid}')"><c:out value="${myBeans.f_name} ${myBeans.l_name} (${myBeans.userid})"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>

Comment: this is action class :::
public ActionForward otherprofiless() {
String sql = "Select f_name,userid from mainreg";
        ResultSet rs = SQLC.getData(sql, null);
        List<regForm> myBeans = new ArrayList();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String f_name = rs.getString("f_name");
            String userid = rs.getString("userid");
            myBeans.add(new regForm(f_name,userid));
        }
        request.setAttribute("myBeans", myBeans);
        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

Comment: and this is my bean :::::

public class regForm extends org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm {
 private String f_name = null;
 private String userid= null;

  regForm(String f_name, String userid) {
        this.f_name = f_name;
        this.userid = userid;
    }
}

with getters setters ..

Comment: now how could i use what u said in last comment ..if i have to use more functions .. in same bean

Comment: just add more fields to it and get/set methods.

Comment: i want to keep my constructor empty regForm()     but how to do it in this case ..where i have many queries and functions in regForm(bean)

Comment: and how to retreive then in jsp ?

Comment: Same way as for tName: <c:out value="${myBean.tName}"/>. Just change tName to new property name

Comment: and what about in bean what to do there hmm i mean what i wrote above how i replace myBeans.add(new regForm(f_name,userid))   with some so i dont have to pass these two values to my bean ..